# AWS application load balancer laravel & socket.io

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, socket.io, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a **LARAVEL** website hosted on AWS that has a real-time chat system built in socket io in the same project (server.js file in LARAVELproject) it was working fine but after creating the application load balancer I can't connect to socket (https://domain-name.com:8890) I added listeners for ALB (80 & 443)

Comment: Please provide more infos, what error did you get?

Comment: Alshiekh, did you figure this out? i have the same problem, I have configured the load balancer like this: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/examples/cluster-nginx/nginx.conf

But I'm wondering if it should have its completely own server with those configurations